# why kthread have pid 2 and systemd have PID 1?

Tags: linux, kernel, init, systemd

In the systemd environment, when I performed **ps -auxf**, I see that the kthread has PID of 2 while systemd has PID 1 assigned.

So, who assigns PID 2 to kthread and why is it getting PID 2 when kthread is what that calls **systemd**?

Comment: `systemd` is your `/sbin/init`

Comment: @basile that is true. But the kernel thread is the one that calls /sbin/init. So, why is it picking up PID of 2 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think that `kthreadd` is starting `init` (in your case symlinked to `systemd`).

`init` is started by the kernel initialization. `kthreadd` is started just after. See this [kernel threads](http://www.crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Kernel_threads) wikipage, and, for Linux 4.2, its file [init/main.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/main.c?id=refs/tags/v4.2), function `rest_init`, near lines 397, where you see:

```
/*
 * We need to spawn init first so that it obtains pid 1, however
 * the init task will end up wanting to create kthreads, which, if
 * we schedule it before we create kthreadd, will OOPS.
 */
kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS);
numa_default_policy();
pid = kernel_thread(kthreadd, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES);
```

<sup>So `kthreadd` is *not* starting `init`, but both are started in the kernel before being scheduled, so before starting their execution.</sup>

The static `kernel_init` function (lines 930 - 975 of [init/main.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/main.c?id=refs/tags/v4.2)) has notably:

```
if (execute_command) {
    ret = run_init_process(execute_command);
    if (!ret)
        return 0;
    panic("Requested init %s failed (error %d).",
          execute_command, ret);
}
if (!try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init") ||
    !try_to_run_init_process("/etc/init") ||
    !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/init") ||
    !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh"))
    return 0;
```

so is setting up the *init* process (à la [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)....) and has hardwired `/sbin/init` etc...

And the [`init` process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) has pid 1 for ages (since primordial Unix of the 1970s, and also in old Linux 1.x kernels without kernel threads). It is a strong Unix convention (on which probably a lot of software depends). You can use [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) as your *init* process, but you could also use [sysvinit](https://wiki.debian.org/Debate/initsystem/sysvinit) or simply `bash` (it is sometimes useful to pass `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel thru [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) for repairing purposes) or something else (e.g. [runit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runit))